# JCE Pro - Any good?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I was wondering if anyone has had any valid experience with JCE Pro ? http://www.syntropy.se - javascript obfuscation

Or any other good obfuscation methods for that reason ?

Comment: For those looking - http://javascript-reference.info/javascript-obfuscators-review.htm - pretty good overview of JS obfuscators

Answer (score 0):

We have been using JCE Pro for a while, it has it's problems, sometimes it obfuscates things that shouldn't be obfuscated. You should test every time you obfuscate. This happens rarely, but when that happens it is annoying.

The good thing for me is it ships with Ant Task so I can automate the process.

Overall I recommend JCE Pro.